# C: for a smallish struct, returning struct or returning reference to struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

In C;

If a struct is small, because it mainly consists of pointers to potentially large arrays; would it be "better" for functions to return a pointer to the struct or to return the struct itself?

From what I see;

Disadvantage of the first: requires the function to malloc a very small amount just for the struct itself, if there are tons of such structs, looks wasteful...

Disadvantage of the second: maybe the struct will become larger in later revisions, if there are tons of such structs will have a lot of copying... But maybe since this is on the stack of the thread it is not really bad (I could imagine that maybe even copying does not occur sometimes)?

In addition, it seems that from the point of view of a unified stylistic interface, it is better to choose one and stick to it, even if the cost is some non-optimization for some of the structs in the program?

Comment: To add, if I decide on "pointers", say, then it makes sense for struct members which are themselves one of my other structs, to be pointers to them, for a unified style... And vice versa, if I decide on "no pointers". So in the latter approach, seems that structs might really grow with time...

Comment: Or... _Don't let style dictate substance_.